# Wordpress Rest API - How to get all authors when using get post by slug

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I'm using "get post" by slug to get the post content and for some reason it's only returning a single Author. 
The article contains multiple authors and I was looking for get a list of all authors in a possible array.
[image]

Comment: Out-of-the-box, WordPress posts can be assigned to a single author only. Multi-author posts are possible via third-party plugins (which I'm guessing is what you're using) so you have two choices here: 1) ask the developer of the multi-author plugin to add REST API support to their plugin so the posts endpoints include this data, or 2) include said data yourself in the REST API.

Comment: Thank you. I'll have  a look to see if can add it in the API myself.